# Symbolic Taylor expansion

Tags: sage

I would like to expand the symbol `function $f(x)$` as a Taylor series in SageMath

```
$$\delta f(x)=\delta x\frac{d}{dx}f+\frac12(\delta x)^2\frac{d^2} 
{dx^2}f+O((\delta x)^3)$$
```

with

```
$$\delta x = a_1(\delta t)^{\frac12}+a_2(\delta t)+a_3(\delta t)^{\frac32}+O((\delta t)^2)$$
```

And expand and collect the same power terms of `$\delta t$` up to a designated power, say, `$\frac32$. $f$` is just a symbol, I just need Mathsage to produce the symbols of derivatives `$\frac{d}{dx}$`.

How should one set this up in SageMath?

Comment: Are x and δx related? How are they related? How is δf and f related? I'm not clear as to what is going on.

Comment: @Mochan: Good question. In mathematics, it is a shorthand $\delta f(x):=f(x+\delta x)-f(x)$. I am Taylor expanding $\delta f(x)$.

Comment: Is δt constant? Then it would also make δx constant.

Comment: @Mochan: $\delta t$ is not a constant. It is the key variable.

Comment: So δf dependent on both x and δt? This would be a multi-variate Taylor series.

Comment: Also asked, and answered, as [Ask Sage question 44125: Symbolic Taylor expansion](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/44125).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

```
sage: f = function('f', nargs=1)(x)
sage: f
f(x)
sage: f.taylor(x, 0, 2)
1/2*x^2*D[0, 0](f)(0) + x*D[0](f)(0) + f(0)
```

Comment: Pretty much. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With sympy, you would do something like this to get the Taylor series.

```
import sympy

dt = sympy.Symbol('dt')
a1 = sympy.Symbol('a1')
a2 = sympy.Symbol('a2')
a3 = sympy.Symbol('a3')
dx = a1*dt**(1/2) + a2*dt + a3*dt**(3/2)

from sympy.abc import x
f = sympy.Function('f')(x)
df = dx*sympy.diff(f,x) + 1/2*dx**2*sympy.diff(f,x,2)
df.series(x)
```

This is assuming x and δx are independent.

Comment: I would like the software to produce the Taylor expansion itself rather than I instruct it what to do, which is what your second last script is doing.